# NoMethodError: undefined method 'flat_map'

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I followed all the setup instructions on https://gorails.com/setup/windows/11, and got all the way to the command `rake db:create` and received the error about undefined method 'flat map'. I tried searching and ran the command `rake --trace db:create` and not sure what I am looking for to fix the issue.

Inside /home/edlaier/config/database.yml

```
cat database.yml
/# PostgreSQL. Versions 9.3 and up are supported.
#
# Install the pg driver:
#   gem install pg
# On macOS with Homebrew:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config
# On macOS with MacPorts:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/pg_config
# On Windows:
#   gem install pg
#       Choose the win32 build.
#       Install PostgreSQL and put its /bin directory on your path.
#
# Configure Using Gemfile
# gem "pg"
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: tms_app_development

  # The specified database role being used to connect to postgres.
  # To create additional roles in postgres see `$ createuser --help`.
  # When left blank, postgres will use the default role. This is
  # the same name as the operating system user running Rails.
  #username: tms_app

  # The password associated with the postgres role (username).
  #password:

  # Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses a
  # domain socket that doesn't need configuration. Windows does not have
  # domain sockets, so uncomment these lines.
  #host: localhost

  # The TCP port the server listens on. Defaults to 5432.
  # If your server runs on a different port number, change accordingly.
  #port: 5432

  # Schema search path. The server defaults to $user,public
  #schema_search_path: myapp,sharedapp,public

  # Minimum log levels, in increasing order:
  #   debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1,
  #   log, notice, warning, error, fatal, and panic
  # Defaults to warning.
  #min_messages: notice

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: tms_app_test

# As with config/credentials.yml, you never want to store sensitive information,
# like your database password, in your source code. If your source code is
# ever seen by anyone, they now have access to your database.
#
# Instead, provide the password or a full connection URL as an environment
# variable when you boot the app. For example:
#
#   DATABASE_URL="postgres://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"
#
# If the connection URL is provided in the special DATABASE_URL environment
# variable, Rails will automatically merge its configuration values on top of
# the values provided in this file. Alternatively, you can specify a connection
# URL environment variable explicitly:
#
#   production:
#     url: <%= ENV["MY_APP_DATABASE_URL"] %>
#
# Read https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
# for a full overview on how database connection configuration can be specified.
#
production:
  <<: *default
  database: postgres
  username: edward
  password: xxxx
```

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `flat_map' for "/# PostgreSQL. Versions 9.3 and up are supported.":String
/home/edlaier/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.5/lib/active_record/database_configurations.rb:152:in `build_configs'
/home/edlaier/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.5/lib/active_record/database_configurations.rb:20:in `initialize'
/home/edlaier/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:157:in `new'
/home/edlaier/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:157:in `for_each'
/home/edlaier/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.5/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/home/edlaier/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:232:in `in_namespace'
/home/edlaier/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb:141:in `namespace'
/home/edlaier/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.5/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:29:in `block in <main>'
/home/edlaier/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:232:in `in_namespace'
/home/edlaier/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb:141:in `namespace'
/home/edlaier/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.5/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:9:in `<main>'
/home/edlaier/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.5/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:54:in `load'
/home/edlaier/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.5/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:54:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/home/edlaier/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.5/lib/rails/railtie.rb:286:in `instance_exec'
/home/edlaier/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.5/lib/rails/railtie.rb:286:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/home/edlaier/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.5/lib/rails/railtie.rb:298:in `each'
/home/edlaier/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.5/lib/rails/railtie.rb:298:in `each_registered_block'
/home/edlaier/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.5/lib/rails/railtie.rb:286:in `run_tasks_blocks'
/home/edlaier/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:500:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/home/edlaier/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.5/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:15:in `each'
/home/edlaier/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.5/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:15:in `each'
/home/edlaier/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:500:in `run_tasks_blocks'
/home/edlaier/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `load_tasks'
/home/edlaier/tms-app/Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'
/home/edlaier/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
/home/edlaier/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
/home/edlaier/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:710:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/edlaier/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/edlaier/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/edlaier/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
/home/edlaier/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
/home/edlaier/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/edlaier/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/home/edlaier/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/edlaier/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/bin/rake:25:in `load'
/home/edlaier/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/bin/rake:25:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Please add the failing code and console outputs (backtrace)

Comment: Remove the first line and the `/` on the second and try again. Also as mentioned if you setup a username and password for postgres you will need to add those to the configuration as well.

Comment: @engineersmnky the first line was just a command, outside of the file, I did remove the backslash and it worked. I must have accidentally added it at point of opening?

Answer (score 2):

Your error is pretty clear about the source of your issue, which is that String objects aren't collections and don't have a #flat_map method.

> NoMethodError: undefined method `flat_map' for "/# PostgreSQL. Versions 9.3 and up are supported.":String

Also, since you have an invalid comment right at the top of your YAML file:

```yaml
/# PostgreSQL. Versions 9.3 and up are supported.
```

parsing the file is the most likely problem. At least now you know where the String is coming from, and what the error means. You can continue to debug from there if needed.