# Rails rake db:create error - NoMethodError: undefined method `flat_map' for "gem \"pg\"":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, apple-m1

I am trying to build a Ruby on Rails project with a Postgresql database. I am using an M1 MacBook with macOS Ventura 13.2. I installed Docker, and made a Postgres container with docker compose up. I also installed PGAdmin. I have installed Postgresql locally with Homebrew. Now I am trying to build a Ruby on Rails app using Postgresql, but when I run the command rake db:create I get this error: NoMethodError: undefined method `flat_map' for "gem "pg"":String

[image]

Here is my config/database.yml file

[image]

I have already tried to update the pg gem (there wasn't an update to be done). I have also checked for proper comments on my config file, but it all looks fine to me. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NoMethodError: undefined method 'flat\_map'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76535318/nomethoderror-undefined-method-flat-map). Line 16 in the screenshot (database.yml) shows `gem "pg"` remove or comment out this line

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it the error seems to be in the Gemfile.

You can open the file and make sure it looks like this:

```
gem "pg"
```

If there are any trailing spaces front or back, and the quotes are incorrect try fixing them and running the command again.

It could also be that your PC doesn't have the gem installed correctly so you can first make sure if that dependency is resolved.

If this doesn't work or if your files are correct, could you provide further information?

Comment: I get this error when I type gem pg

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::UnknownCommandError)
    Unknown command pg
 /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:205:in `find_command'
 /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:250:in `invoke_command'
 /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:192:in `process_args'
 /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:150:in `run'

Comment: When I run gem list, the pg gem is listed there